# Get python3: can't find '__main__' module even when I have if __name__ == "__main__": in my file

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I run a py file using a container using sklearn docker image, but I get error

```
python3: can't find '__main__' module
```

my file is something like:

```
def function()
 

if __name__ == "__main__":

function()
```

Comment: "python3: can't find '__main__' module" I'm sorry, you are going to have to elaborate a little more about exactly what you are doing

Comment: I want to know running code in container using predefined docker image of sklearn is different from run it locally. I get the error only when I the script in container.

Answer (score 0):

are you facing the error with the same piece or code or it's just for reference?
From what I can see is you're missing ": "after method declaration.

```
def function():
    print("test")


if "__main__" == __name__:
    function()
```

Comment: I do not have syntax error, my problem is when I run it using docker image in container.